# ReferenceError: connection is not defined in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Both .js files are in the same folder. And I'm attempting to run the app, but I recieve that connection is not defined in user.js. It's on the row where query is called on connection that it says that it's not defined.

index.js

```
var exports = module.exports = {};

var user = require('./user');

exports.User = user;
exports.startCon = startCon;

var mysql = require('mysql2');

function startCon() {
    return mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: 'root',
        database: 'users'
    })
}
```

user.js

```
var dal = require('./index');

function User(){
    this.connection = null;
}

User.prototype.getAll = function(cb){
      this.connection = dal.startCon();

      connection.query('SELECT * FROM user;', function (error, data) {
        if(!error){
                cb(null, data);
        }
        else {
                console.log("Error Selecting : %s ", error );
                cb(error);
        }
    });

    connection.end();
}

module.exports = User;
```

Comment: `this.connection` isn't the same variable as `connection`

Comment: Silly misstake, yeah that's true!

Answer (score -2):

Try close connection inside the callback function

```
callback() {
    connection.close()
}
```

> And this module really weird

You need construct connection instance inside function

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

let doSmth = function(userId) {

    let connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : 'localhost',
        user     : 'root',
        password : '',
        database : 'test'
    });
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        connection.query({
                sql: 'SELECT `address` FROM `User` WHERE `user_id` = ?'
            },
            [userId],
            function (error, results, fields) {
                console.log(error, results)
                if(!error) {
                    var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results));
                    resolve(obj)
                } else {
                    reject(error)
                }
            }
        );
    })
}
module.exports = {
    doSmth
};
```